# AspNet Gridview Display

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am working on a small inventory webform application using visual studio 2017 community in asp.net. Initially when I started developing this application the GridView was displaying by applying style using jquery properly. But now its display has been distorted. I have already unistalled and installed jquery but the problem still persists. Currently jQuery 3.1.1 is installed in my application although there is an update i.e. 3.2.1 is available which I am not able to update due to the following error:

> "'jQuery 3.2.1' is not compatible with 'AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery 3.1.1 constraint: jQuery (>= 3.1.1 && < 3.1.2)'."

Could you please give me a way to fix the gridview display style problem. I am attaching the sample of the gridview:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what the problem is; spacing?

Comment: yeah ... the problem is spacing between columns and rows ..

Comment: Should be pretty easy with css or css-via-jquery but we can't really help without a working sample. A simple css fix might be `td { padding: 2px 4px; }`.

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="StockID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BackColor="White"   BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

Answer (score 1):

Create a style like this:

```
<style>
    .gvw th, .gvw td { padding: 2px 6px; } /* change as needed. */
</style>
```

Inside the gridview add css style:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGvw" runat="server" CssClass="gvw">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks wazz it's working like before. But what was the problem with GridView is still a mystery.